# Newborn kitten, cold and won't nurse

Tags: cats

My cat, Peach, had her first litter of kittens on May 9th. The first two were born together with one placenta and two umbilical cords attached to that placenta. She had 3 others.

The twins seems great at first glance. The first one to come out is sucking wonderfully and progressing very well. The second will not suck for longer than two minutes and only if I put it's nose to the nipple.

It's began to get cold even though it's being warmed up by mom and other kittens. It doesn't meow hardly. It's half the size of the other kittens. I've been doing nutrical, bottle feeding, stimulating.